# How to use Google maps in Flutter with navigation

Tags: google-maps, flutter

How does app like Uber and others show two location on screen and the path between them? Does google provide that functionality to developers or is it proprietary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_polyline) package to draw routes with google maps. You can use the helper methods like these:

```
  await googleMapPolyline.getCoordinatesWithLocation(
      origin: LatLng(40.677939, -73.941755),
      destination: LatLng(40.698432, -73.924038),
      mode:  RouteMode.driving);
```

and

```
  await googleMapPolyline.getPolylineCoordinatesWithAddress(
      origin:  '55 Kingston Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11213, USA',
      destination:  '8007 Cypress Ave, Glendale, NY 11385, USA',
      mode:  RouteMode.driving);
```

to make a route between points.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_polyline_points#-readme-tab- Use this package , the above package is discontinued